# Reading ASCII with field delimiter as ctrl A and line delimiting as \n into python

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

I have an ASCII dataset that has ctrl A field delimiting and \n as the line delimiter. I am looking to read this into Python and am wondering how to deal with it. In particular I would like to be able to read this information into a pandas dataframe.

I currently have;

```
import pandas as pd
input = pd.read_csv('000000_0', sep='^A')
```

The error I then get is

```
_main__:1: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does 
not support regex separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
```

I then don't know how I am specifying the line delimiter too.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have any problems using the usual methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `sep=chr(1)`

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

mycsv = """a{0}b{0}c
d{0}e{0}f""".format(chr(1))


pd.read_csv(StringIO(mycsv), sep=chr(1))

   a  b  c
0  d  e  f
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of mentioning "^A" mention the hex code. Its works like a charm

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('000000_0', sep='\x01')
```

Answer (score 0):

If by `CTRL+A` you mean the ASCII-Code for `SOH` (start of heading), try splitting your data on newline first to get the rows, and split these on `"\x01"`, which is the hex code for `SOH`. But without any code, data, expected result or error message, this is mostly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
reader = csv.reader(open("/Users/778123/Documents/Splunk/data/DMS3^idms_core^20200723140421.csv",newline=None), delimiter=',')

print(reader)

writer = csv.writer(open("/Users/778123/Documents/Splunk/data/DMS3^idms_core^test.csv", 'w'), delimiter=chr(1), quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

writer.writerows(reader)
```

Answer (score -1):

Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library is pretty good at reading delimited files ;-)

Taking an example from the docs linked above:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        print ', '.join(row)
```

This will automatically iterate over the lines in the file (thus handle the newline characters), and you can set the delimiter as shown.

Comment: The issue is how the OP can properly write the specific delimiter in their file (`'\x01'`, usually entered as ctrl+a), which your answer doesn't address. To make this example with `csv` useful for this question, please show an example with that delimiter.